# wp_editor different parameters for id and name

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

i am creating **wp_editor** in wordpress as below

```
<?php

$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );

?>
```

but i want to pass both ***id and name*** differently like below

```
<?php

$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
$editor_name = 'mycustomeditorname';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id,$editor_name );

?>
```

is there any way i can do it in **wordpress**

Comment: What is this accomplishing for you?

Comment: i have n number of editor to create and i want both id and name to be different.i want the name as array and id unique identifier

Comment: Accept an answer please. Both answers work!

Comment: @designtocode - I needed this becaues I am creating tinycme editors in a loop but I need to handle the post request of each one and because they all have different ids (tinycme_N) I was unable to work with the post. Giving them all the same name made it possible to handle post requests for them.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this way. It's works fine for me.

```
<?php
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
$settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'mycustomeditorname' );
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
?>
```

Look for other wp_editor settings like add class name,css etc here.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $content = '';
 $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
 wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, array( 'textarea_name' => 'mycustomeditorname' ) );
?>
```